# Android emulator shuts down during startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

the emulator (shipped with Android Studio) stopped working all of a sudden on a Windows 10 machine. It shuts down Android during bootstrap:

```
[    9.123392] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
[    9.126263] Power down.
```

I have some suspicions: memory, host drivers problem and/or permissions but I am still uncertain about the exact reason for failure. There is a bunch of concerning things happening. For example:

---

```
40:6): avc: denied { dac_override } for pid=1338 comm="init.ranchu-cor" capability=1 scontext=u:r:goldfish_setup:s0 tcontext=u:r:goldfish_setup:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
[    2.147050] init: Service 'ranchu-setup' (pid 1338) exited with status 1
```

Not sure if I shall be concerned about SELinux messages though.

---

Or a bunch of `unable to open` reports like the following:

```
[    2.150052] init: write_file: Unable to open '/sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable': No such file or directory
```

Please find verbose emulator and OS bootstrap logs here:

https://github.com/wojciechfornal/public/blob/master/android/android-emulator/android-emulator-shutdown-issue/avd.log

I've also added logs from OSX where emulator launched without issue. Android started and then I powered it off manually.

https://github.com/wojciechfornal/public/blob/master/android/android-emulator/android-emulator-shutdown-issue/avd-osx.log

It looks like some error conditions happen in both cases and I consider them irrelevant. One thing is left and it is related to `ranchu` virtual board (based on qemu 2.8). Maybe this fails because of buggy media drivers on my host machine?

Meanwhile I will give Genymotion and/or Android SDK on Mac a try.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happened to me too. The solution is to update all the required components. To do that go to the "Tools" menu at the top in "Android Studio" and choose "SDK Manager". Click on "System Settings" in the left menu and go to "Android SDK".

1. Go to "SDK Tools" tab and see any update is required. If required update those by clicking the tick mark and pressing OK or whatever it requires.
2. Go to "SDK Platform" tab and tick the checkbox "Show Package Details". Then If you see any update is required/available then update those also.

After all that mentioned previously, restart "Android Studio" and try to run the emulator and it should work hopefully and not shut down after launch.